# Failed to install OpenCV on Ubuntu 16.04!

Tags: python, opencv

I am following the instructions from [OpenCV Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) and have some failures.
I followed until the step 2 and run `./opencv.sh` shown there, but resulted in

```
//home/voo-doo/anaconda2/lib/libQtGui.so.4: undefined reference to `png_get_channels@PNG16_0'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/cpp-tutorial-pnp_detection.dir/build.make:319:   
recipe for target 'bin/cpp-tutorial-pnp_detection' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/cpp-tutorial-pnp_detection] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7367: recipe for target 'samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/cpp-tutorial-pnp_detection.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/cpp-tutorial-pnp_detection.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/cpp-example-videocapture_starter
[ 73%] Built target example_videocapture_starter
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
[sudo] password for voo-doo: 
sudo: checkinstall: command not found
OpenCV 3.2.0 ready to be used
voo-doo@voodoo-HP-envy:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from cv2.cv import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
```

I couldn't find any solution to this from that documentation.

Overall, I just need to install openCV and use it through python environment.

Question:  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: @muru,  I see, I edited my question content. Is it OK now?

Comment: Unless you specifically *need* a newer version, you should be able to install `python-opencv` directly from the Ubuntu `universe` repository

Comment: @steeldriver How can I do so, can you write down the steps or guide to links please?